# Get user wall post in facebook

Tags: facebook

How to get a user’s wall posts and get comments on wall by providing the user’s credential(i.e. username and password)

For Example:www.facebook.com?username=abc&password=abc&get=wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to collect the access_token of the user . and then if you want to get all the data from that user's wall you can try this

```
<?php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$user_id}/feed/?access_token={$access_token}";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And if you want to get all the comments of a post, first you have to get the wall post id which you can get easily from the above code and then

```
<?php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$wall_post_id}?access_token={$access_token}";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Good Luck

Comment: How to get email id of user who posts the wall because user info does not contains email id

Comment: If the user dont allow you to get his/her email address you cant get that . So when the user is installing the app you have to ask them for  the email permission .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot authenticate user using his credentials with any of SDK Facebook provide.

Same goes for every API Facebook expose.

Facebook uses OAuth2 for authentication and you really doesn't need user's credentials to work with API

Comment: How to get email id of user who posts the wall because user info does not contains email id –

Comment: You need to aks user to grant `email` permission. This is different question which was answered number of times on [so], use search and you easily will find answers...